# How to get the selected options of a multiselect in Elm?

Tags: html-select, elm

I've seen [what is required for a getting the selected index of a single select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32426042) but I'm interested in getting all of the selected options from a multi select. I haven't been able to work out how to do this.

I've attempted the following but I suspect the Json decoder is failing. I'm not 100% sure of that though, because the decoding happens in the virtual dom code and any errors there are thrown away.

```
type Msg
= SetMultipleInts (List Int)

-- I'm not seeing the SetMultipleInts message when I click on the multiselect
view model =
    div []
        [ select (onSelect SetMultipleInts) (List.map myOption [1..4]) ]

myOption : Int -> Html Msg
myOption id =
    option [ value (toString id) ] [ text <| "Option " ++ (toString id) ]

-- I'm not seeing anything happen in the onchange
onMultiSelect : (List Int -> msg) -> List (Html.Attribute msg)
onMultiSelect msg =
    [ on "change" (Json.map msg targetSelectedOptions), multiple True ]

targetSelectedOptions : Json.Decoder (List Int)
targetSelectedOptions =
    Json.at [ "target", "selectedOptions" ] (Json.list (Json.at [ "value" ] Json.int))
```

Can I do this without having to use ports?

Comment: Where is onMultSelect meant to be used? it is defined and unused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The decoder fails because `event.target.selectedOptions` is not a
javascript array.  When you cannot use `Json.Decode.list`, you
can use `Json.Decode.keyValuePairs`.

Here is the example how you can use it.
You may want to change `extractValues` below depending
on how you want to react to empty selection and such.

```elm
targetSelectedOptions : Json.Decoder (List String)
targetSelectedOptions =
  let
    maybeValues =
      Json.at [ "target", "selectedOptions" ]
        <| Json.keyValuePairs
        <| Json.maybe ("value" := Json.string)
    extractValues mv =
      Ok (List.filterMap snd mv)
  in Json.customDecoder maybeValues extractValues
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone need a multiselect in Elm, I rewrote a fully working example in Elm 0.19:

https://ellie-app.com/g7WrS9cV4zVa1

```
module Main exposing (main)

import Browser
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes
import Html.Events
import Json.Decode


type alias Model =
    { value : List ( String, Maybe String ) }


init : Model
init =
    { value = [] }


type Msg
    = SetMultipleInts (List ( String, Maybe String ))


update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
    case msg of
        SetMultipleInts value ->
            { model | value = value }


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ select
            [ Html.Events.on "change"
                (Json.Decode.map SetMultipleInts targetSelectedOptions)
            , Html.Attributes.multiple True
            ]
            (List.map myOption (List.range 1 4))
        , div []
            [ text <|
                Debug.toString
                    (model
                        |> .value
                        |> List.map Tuple.second
                        |> List.filterMap identity
                    )
            ]
        ]


targetSelectedOptions : Json.Decode.Decoder (List ( String, Maybe String ))
targetSelectedOptions =
    Json.Decode.at [ "target", "selectedOptions" ] <|
        Json.Decode.keyValuePairs <|
            Json.Decode.maybe (Json.Decode.at [ "value" ] Json.Decode.string)


myOption : Int -> Html Msg
myOption id =
    option [ Html.Attributes.value (String.fromInt id) ]
        [ text <| "Option " ++ String.fromInt id ]


main : Program () Model Msg
main =
    Browser.sandbox
        { init = init
        , view = view
        , update = update
        }
```